# after onPanResponderRelease,auto animation moving does not work correctly

Tags: react-native

My sample code is to auto move a distance after onPanResponderRelease of PanResponder(looks like a object moving inertia).

When I drag the content and release finger(or release dragging in simulator), the content works correctly(it moved a distance automaticlly).
But when I touch quickly(or click once in simulator),the content moves a distance and back to other position.It has problem because the content should not move with a quick touching.

What's the problem?
Here is my code(it can directly paste and run in app.js).

```
    import React from 'react';
import { View, StyleSheet, PanResponder, Animated, Text, Button, } from 'react-native';

export default class App extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this._layout = { x: 0, y: 0, width: 0, height: 0, };
        this._value = { x: 100, y: 100, };
    }

    componentWillMount() {
        this._animatedValue = new Animated.ValueXY({ x: 100, y: 100 });
        this._animatedValue.addListener((value) => {
            this._value = value;
        });

        this._panResponder = PanResponder.create({
            onStartShouldSetPanResponder: (evt, gestureState) => true,
            onMoveShouldSetPanResponder: (evt, gestureState) => ((gestureState.dx != 0) && (gestureState.dy != 0)),

            onPanResponderGrant: (e, gestureState) => {
                this._animatedValue.setOffset({ x: this._value.x, y: this._value.y });
            },

            onPanResponderMove: Animated.event([
                null,
                { dx: this._animatedValue.x, dy: this._animatedValue.y },
            ]),

            onPanResponderRelease: () => {
                this._animatedValue.flattenOffset();
                Animated.timing(
                    this._animatedValue,
                    {
                        toValue: { x: this._value.x, y: this._value.y + 100, },
                        duration: 600,
                    }
                ).start(() => {
                    // animation finished
                });
            }
        });
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <View style={styles.container}>
                <Animated.View
                    style={[
                        styles.box,
                        {
                            left: this._animatedValue.x,
                            top: this._animatedValue.y,
                        },
                    ]}
                    {...this._panResponder.panHandlers}
                >
                    <Text>{'This is a test'}</Text>
                    <Button
                        title={'Click Me'}
                        onPress={() => console.log('Yes, I clicked.')}
                    />
                </Animated.View>
            </View>
        );
    }
}

var styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        flex: 1,
    },
    box: {
        width: 200,
        height: 200,
        borderWidth: 1,
    },
});
```

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure how much this matters but you are not adding the event listener in the suggested way: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/animated#event

Try adding it like this:

```
componentWillMount() {
    this._animatedValue = new Animated.ValueXY({ x: 100, y: 100 });

    // REMOVE THIS
    //this._animatedValue.addListener((value) => {
    //     this._value = value;
    //});

    this._panResponder = PanResponder.create({
        onStartShouldSetPanResponder: (evt, gestureState) => true,
        onMoveShouldSetPanResponder: (evt, gestureState) => ((gestureState.dx != 0) && (gestureState.dy != 0)),

        onPanResponderGrant: (e, gestureState) => {
            this._animatedValue.setOffset({ x: this._value.x, y: this._value.y });
        },

        onPanResponderMove: Animated.event([
            null,
            { dx: this._animatedValue.x, dy: this._animatedValue.y },
        ],
            {
SEE HERE--->>>          listener: this.onMove
            }
        ),

        onPanResponderRelease: () => {
            this._animatedValue.flattenOffset();
            Animated.timing(
                this._animatedValue,
                {
                    toValue: { x: this._value.x, y: this._value.y + 100, },
                    duration: 600,
                }
            ).start(() => {
                // animation finished
            });
        }
    });
}

AND SEE HERE --->>> 

onMove() {
    var { x, y } = this.animatedValue;
    this._value.x = x;
    this._value.y = y;

}
```

Also try making your Animated.View `position:absolute`

Now, it looks like the code is doing this:

1. Set 'Animated offset' to be equal to 'value offset' (onPanResponderGrant)
2. Set the 'Animated offset' to be equal to 'dx' 'dy' (onPanResponderMove)
3. set 'value' to be equal to 'Animated value' (Event Listener)
4. set the 'animated value' to be equal to 'value' (onPanResponderRelease)

Between steps one and two you are setting the offset twice without flattening (again, not sure how much that matters).

Between steps three and four you are setting 'value offset' equal to 'Animated Value offset' and then 'Animated value offset' to be equal to 'Value offset' again - seems redundant

Comment: I test the codes with your guide,but the same problem occurs. When I drag the animate view,new error occured:JSON value '183.5[object Object] of type NSString cannot be converted to a YGValue. Did you forget the % or pt suffix?'. Thanks!

Comment: I wrote a new version and got the result with your guide(my answer is blow).Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a new version and got the result.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
    StyleSheet, View, Text, Animated, PanResponder,
} from 'react-native';

export default class App extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this._value = { x: 0, y: 0 };
        this.pan = new Animated.ValueXY({ x: 0, y: 0 });
    }

    componentWillMount() {
        this.pan.addListener((value) => {
            this._value = value;
        });

        this.panResponder = PanResponder.create({
            onStartShouldSetPanResponder: (evt, gestureState) => true,
            onMoveShouldSetPanResponder: (evt, gestureState) => ((gestureState.dx != 0) && (gestureState.dy != 0)),

            onPanResponderGrant: (e, gestureState) => {
                this.pan.setOffset({ x: this._value.x, y: this._value.y });
                this.pan.setValue({ x: 0, y: 0 });
            },

            onPanResponderMove: Animated.event([null, {
                dx: this.pan.x,
                dy: this.pan.y
            }]),
            onPanResponderRelease: (e, gesture) => {
                this.pan.flattenOffset();

                const { x, y } = this._value;
                Animated.timing(
                    this.pan,
                    {
                        toValue: { x, y: y + 50 },
                        duration: 600,
                    },
                ).start(() => {
                    // animation finished
                });
            }
        });
    }

    componentWillUnmount() {
        this.pan.removeAllListener();
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
                <View style={styles.draggableContainer}>
                    <Animated.View
                        {...this.panResponder.panHandlers}
                        style={[
                            this.pan.getLayout(),
                            styles.square,
                        ]}>
                        <Text>Drag me!</Text>
                    </Animated.View>
                </View>

            </View>
        );
    }
}

let styles = StyleSheet.create({
    draggableContainer: {
        position: 'absolute',
        top: 165,
        left: 76.1,
    },
    square: {
        backgroundColor: 'red',
        width: 72,
        height: 72,
        borderWidth: 1,
    }
});
```

the previous version has some problems because I didn't know the react-native animation.

there are several points about the codes:

1)animation view should be wrapped by a position:absolute view.

2)the animation value/valueXY is a relative position.

3)addListener works right.

4)valueXY is a combine object with two value object.
but the addListener param is an object with x/y, like this: {x:0,y:0}

(So, valueXY and listener param cannot assign directly)

5)animation will add the offset of value.

after flattenOffset, the offset will be added to value.

[flattenOffset](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/0.37/animated.html#flattenoffset)